# What is the name for the set of all texts expressing the same event?

Tags: terminology

suppose you want to express an event like "a man picking up an apple from the dirty floor and puts it onto the table", you have many possible ways to formulate a text expressing this even, for instance (with maybe some tiny semantical variations):

- A man, an apple, a table and the event of him pickin it up and placing it on.
- a man picks up the apple. a man puts the apple onto the table.
- the apple is placed upon the table by a man.
- there is a man. there is an apple. there is a table. there is an event. the event is the man is placing the apple on the table.

Is there a particular name for a set/class that contains all the possible ways to express the event?

If not, is there something (distantly) similar?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraphrase

Answer (score 1):

This is the study of "event co-reference" and is something of a challenge for computational linguists who may want to associate different texts describing aspects or perspectives of the "same" event.